# Is there a CONCAT_WS method in JPQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, jpql, concatenation, concat-ws

I am wondering if there is something like the `CONCAT_WS` method in `JPQL` as I found it in the `MYSQL documentation` here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

Anyone ever stumbled over anything comparable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not. JPQL does have following String functions: CONCAT, LENGTH, LOWER, SUBSTRING, TRIM, and UPPER. Only way in with older JPQL versions is to simply repeat separator between each value in CONCAT:

```
SELECT CONCAT(se.string1, ';', se.string2) 
FROM SomeEntity se
```

With JPQL in the JPA 2.1 specification implementations it is possible to call database functions as follows (first arguments is name of the function, others are arguments to function):

```
SELECT FUNCTION('CONCAT_WS', ';', se.string1, se.string2) 
FROM SomeEntity se
```

Older EclipseLink versions have same functionality via `FUNC` keyword.